# grep date from line

Tags: c#, unix, grep

Trying to grep date from below line in c#. What should be the regular expression for it in c#?
Also wanted to grep string after "as" word in below line i.e. "xyx". This xyz would vary in different lines. Need regular expression in c#

```
<p3> 2016-07-15T22:33:33.994Z TTT-PPPP-01 Xtvc[10653]: Connections: authenticated: 10.18.77.11::2000, as xyz (c permissions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Matches( text, @"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).+?, as (\w+)"  );
```

answers are in groups 1 and 2

\d{4} means two digits in a row  then there are dashes (-) and colons (:) so it reads

```
4 digits
dash
2 digits
dash
2 digits
T
2 digits
colon
2 digits
colon
2 digits
dot
3 digits
```

.+? means any character, one or more matches, not greedy
then you get
, as

and I put

/w+ meaning any word character, one or more matches to get the "xyz"

You may need to modify that part depending on what can show up in the "xyz" spot.